# Scoping for HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js

So I would like the variable pass_or_fail to be assighned inside of the .then clause and for that assignment to be reflected outside of the .then clause

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/signup?username='+this.username+'&password='+this.password+'&password2='+this.password2)
  //make get request to API with what USER entered into the search bar in the query string
    .then(response => {
        if(response.body== "success"){

          this.pass_or_fail=response.body;

        }
    }

)

   console.log(this.pass_or_fail);
    if(this.pass_or_fail=="success"){
    this.$router.push({name:'landing-page'});
    }

  //set sources variable to our response


}
```

However when I console.log(this.pass_or_fail) outside of the .then clause the variable has not been assigned to response.body. Any ideas why the change inside the .then clause is not being reflected outside of the clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post is an async request, meaning that when you log `this.pass_or_fail`, the function passed to the `then` method hasn't fired yet.

You'll need to put any code depending on the result of the post request inside of the function being passed to `then()`:

```
this.$http.post('yoururl')
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.body == "success") {
      this.pass_or_fail = response.body;

      console.log(this.pass_or_fail);

      this.$router.push({ name: 'landing-page' });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attempting to synchronously get the value of `this.pass_or_fail` while it's result is still obtained. I imagine it returns undefined. You need to "wait" for the response, before you can use it. The simplest way is to handle your logic inside the `then` callback. If you don't want to do that, you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)